# Converting datetimes to timestamps and back again

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I'm having some trouble with datetime in Python. I tried converting a datetime to a timestamp and then back again and no matter how I try the end result is not the same. I always end up with a datetime of datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1998).

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999))
b = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a)

print(b)
```

Comment: I think it is because of floating point operations, if you print a, you will find the value to be `1391144380.001999`. And on converting it back, it loses the last bit. The same will not happen if it is not so close to the next decimal value: `(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1996)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known [Python 3.4 issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue23517):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> local = datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(local.timestamp())
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1998)
```

Note: the microsecond is gone. The `.timestamp()` already returns result that is slightly less than `1999` microseconds:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> local.timestamp()
1391126380.001999
>>> Decimal(local.timestamp())
Decimal('1391126380.0019989013671875')
```

[The rounding is fixed in the next 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 releases](http://bugs.python.org/issue23517#msg250974):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> local = datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(local.timestamp())
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999)
```

To workaround the issue, you could use the explicit formula:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> local = datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999)
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(local.timestamp())
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1998) # UTC time
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=local.timestamp())
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999) # UTC time
```

Note: the input in all examples is the local time but the result is UTC time in the last one.

Comment: You could probably also just add `0.0000004` to the `timestamp`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: rounding is a subtle issue. Obvious solutions often breaks. [Read the discussion](http://bugs.python.org/issue23517).

Comment: My constant was carefully chosen to work no matter what rounding mode is used. Although `0.00000025` might be better.

Comment: @MarkRansom: if it works; it deserve its own answer: with explanation, prove, and tests

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've posted an answer with explanation and tests, although the proof is probably lacking.

Answer (score 3):

That last number is microseconds ... are the internals that accurate? Let's find out.

```
counter={}
for i in range(0,1000000,43): 
   # fuzz up some random-ish dates
   d = datetime.datetime( 1990+(i%20), 1+(i%12), 1+(i%28), i%24, i%60, i%60, i)
   ts=datetime.datetime.timestamp( d)
   b = b=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
   msdif=d.microsecond-b.microsecond 
   if msdif in counter:
     counter[msdif] += 1
   else:
     counter[msdif]=1
   assert b.day==d.day and b.hour==d.hour and b.minute==d.minute and b.second=d.second

  >>>
  >>> counter
  {1: 23256}
  >>>
```

I do believe you have found an off-by-one-microsecond error in the datetime library, unless there is something perverse buried in the specifications.

(I was expecting a spread around zero, reflecting rounding errors of some sort)

Comment: Why doesn't `counter` have a count for `0`?

Comment: Because converting to and from timestamp is consistently off by one microsecond. Bug not rounding error!

Answer (score 1):

Very few floating point numbers with a decimal fraction can be exactly represented as a binary floating point number; there will usually be some very small error. Sometimes it will be smaller than the desired number, and sometimes it will be larger, but it should always be very very close. Your example's exact value is `1391147980.0019989013671875` which is within 0.1 microsecond of what you specified.

The conversion from a floating point `timestamp` back to a `datetime` should employ rounding to make sure the round-trip conversion gives the same value as the original. As noted by [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771429/5987), this was entered as a bug against Python 3.4; it is claimed to be fixed in later releases, but it still exists in Python 3.5.0 using the same values as given in the question. Running a test similar to [nigel222](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768464/5987) shows an almost 50/50 split between exact matches and results that are low by 1 microsecond.

Since you know that the original value was an integral number of microseconds, you can add an offset that ensures the binary floating point value is always higher than the decimal value while still being small enough that it doesn't affect the result when properly rounded. Since rounding should occur at 0.5 microseconds the ideal offset would be half of that, or 0.25 microseconds.

Here are the results in Python 3.5.0:

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999))
>>> b = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a)
>>> a
1391147980.001999
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1998)

>>> b = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a + 0.00000025)
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 30, 23, 59, 40, 1999)

>>> counter={}
>>> for i in range(0,1000000):
   # fuzz up some random-ish dates
   d = datetime.datetime(1990+(i%20), 1+(i%12), 1+(i%28), i%24, i%60, i%60, i)
   ts = datetime.datetime.timestamp(d)
   b = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts + 0.00000025)
   msdif = d.microsecond - b.microsecond 
   if msdif in counter:
     counter[msdif] += 1
   else:
     counter[msdif]=1
   assert b.day==d.day and b.hour==d.hour and b.minute==d.minute and b.second==d.second

>>> counter
{0: 1000000}
```

Comment: it *is* fixed in Python 3.5 (the current in development version of 3.5, future `3.5.1`). My answer explicitly says  "**the next** 3... releases"

Comment: note: the fixed version in Python 3.4+ uses `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` mode (default for floating-point numbers and `round()` method). `+ 0.00000025`  breaks it: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(-1.5/1000000 + 0.00000025) != datetime.utcfromtimestamp(-1.5/1000000)` on Python versions without the bug (and Python 2.7).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I just pulled down the latest binary build of Python 3 tonight, so that's what I tested against. I never considered negative timestamps, thanks for that example. Python 2.7 doesn't have the `timestamp` method so there's no problem there.

Comment: 3.5.0 was released several days ago and therefore it can't be considered "the next" release. The change is applied to 3.4, 3.5 and future 3.6 branches.