# Python converting datetime to timestamp and back to datetime does not return original datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I run code to verify that timestamps converted to datetime objects are equal to the datetime objects that I expect them to be, but I get strange results.

```
import datetime
import pytz

local_tz=pytz.timezone('UTC')
time = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 16, 17, 53, 54, tzinfo=local_tz)
converted_time_1 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(time.strftime("%s"))).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)
converted_time_2 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(time.strftime("%s"))).astimezone(local_tz)
converted_time_3 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(time.strftime("%s")))

print('time:', time)
print('converted_time_1:', converted_time_1)
print('converted_time_2:', converted_time_2)
print('converted_time_3:', converted_time_3)
```

The output is for all converted timestamps is strange:

```
time: 2017-10-16 17:53:54+00:00
converted_time_1: 2017-10-16 15:53:54+00:00
converted_time_2: 2017-10-16 12:53:54+00:00
converted_time_3: 2017-10-16 15:53:54
```

Please advise how I can convert a datetime object to a timestamp and back to a datetime object, and be confident that I will receive the same original datetime object.

Note that this is different to this question [Converting datetimes to timestamps and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767394/converting-datetimes-to-timestamps-and-back-again) where the problem related to floating point precision.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  But I will guess that you concern is the lack of timezone info on `converted_time_3`.  The conversion to a unix timestamp will lose the timezone.  What else was expected?

Comment: My question is that something as simple as converting a datetime to a timestamp and then back to a datetime again doesn't give the desired time \of 17:53pm. I never expected converted_time_3 to work, I showed it to contrast it to converted_time_1 and converted_time_2.